# PHP URL Encode - hyperlink variable

Tags: php, html, url, hyperlink

This is a link I have as part of my .php page.

```
<li><a href="http://localhost/Information.php?AI=<?php echo $_GET['AssignedI'] ?>">Stats</a></li>
```

'GET' is used to obtain the variable from the URL of the current page (not Information.php). The URL for the current page is `http://localhost/Current.php?AssignedI=AI03#`

`AssignedI` = `AI03` (it is a string).

When selecting the link, and the Information.php opens, the URL is displayed as:
Information.php?AI=%27

I understand that %27 is the actually `'` - when decoded into text. However, how can I make it so that it displays the actual `AssignedI` - i.e. 'AI03'.

On the Information.php, I have the following code:

```
$AI =  $_GET['AI'];
echo $AI;
```

This outputs `'`.

I have been trying to figure this out for a while so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing math here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, this is part of my .php page. I am trying to add a variable to a hyperlink.

Comment: Must be some of that "new" math @Fred-ii-

Comment: There's something I obviously don't understand about the `+` signs. You wanting to concatenate in PHP or JS?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please take a look at the edited code.

Comment: Sorry, can't; now I gotta run. Maybe someone else can help; *cheers*

Comment: <li><a href="http://localhost/Information.php?AI=<?php echo $_GET[AssignedI] ?>">Stats</a></li>

like that?

Comment: @Lil'Monkey This outputs the same result as in my question.

Comment: the problem in your example up there is that you are manualy adding the ' and " in your url. yet you dont have to because you are ecoing server side code to the html and not doing concatenations ;)

Comment: sorry for any typos by the way main language is french here ;)

Answer (score 0):

AssignedI = AI03

if i understand the output you want is

```
<a href="http://localhost/Information.php?AI=AI03">Stats</a>
```

you do not need all those single and double quote i think you are mixing the server side code and client side code

Server side :

```
<?php echo $_GET[AssignedI] ?>
```

your server will find all the php tag and output them as html in the file so basically your echo will be output to the link before the browser even read the link

```
<li>
<a href="http://localhost/Information.php?AI=<?php echo $_GET[AssignedI] ?>">Stats</a>
</li>
```

this should ouput what you want. without the ' ... then once you click the link in information.php

```
$AI =  $_GET['AI'];
echo $AI;
```

should echo AI03 with no quote

Comment: Thanks for answering.  AI03 is already a string. I have tried your solution yet still end up with `'`. Please take a look at my now edited question.

Comment: I'd like to add that 'GET' is used to obtain the variable from the URL of the current page (not Information.php). The URL for the current page is `http://localhost/Current.php?AssignedI=AI03#`

Comment: i get what your trying to do i just dont get why you would have a quote in the string ;P

Comment: also i would put a ; after my echo 

<?php echo $_GET['AssignedI']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this an alternative way.

This is my edited hyperlink:
`<li><a href="http://localhost/Information.php?AI=<?php echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -4)?>">Stats</a></li>`

I obtained the current URL `http://localhost/Current.php?AssignedI=AI03#`, using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and the last four characters, which contained the 'AI' were obtained (using `substr(..., -4)`.